# Haskell's "permutations" function defined oddly

Tags: haskell

If I wanted to find the permutations of a list, I know that the number of permutations is given by the multinomial coefficient. For example, "MISSISSIPPI" has 11 letters, 'S' appears 4 times, 'I' appears 4 times, 'P' appears twice and 'M' appears once. So the number of permutations of "MISSISSIPPI" is equal to 11!/(4!4!2!) = 34650.

If I load up GHCi and write:

```
ghci> import Data.List
ghci> permutations [1,2,3]
```

It will return

```
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[1,3,2]]
```

as expected.

But if I write

```
ghci> permutations [1,0,0]
```

it will now return

```
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]
```

... which is very disappointing. As there are three elements, and two of them occur twice, one would hope for there only to be 6!/2! = 3 permutations, namely

```
[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

rather than the six generated by treating each element of the list as distinct.

1) Why does Haskell implement "permutations" in the way described above (i.e. treating all elements of a list as distinct?)

2) Are there any standard library functions that calculate the permutations of a list in the "true" sense of permutations?

Comment: Well, you can use `unique` for that, or defining your own, after the permutation: `unique = reverse . nub . reverse`, `unique $ permutations [1, 0, 0]`.

Comment: @MarceloCamargo nice one was just about to write `nub . permutations` - now I am wondering why you need the `reverse` there ... hmmm

Comment: Using nub works, but it's O(n^2) in Haskell's standard library?

Comment: hayoo was able to find [another one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/combinat-0.2.7.0/docs/Math-Combinat-Permutations.html#v:permuteMultiset) - I would guess that this one might be a bit more performant

Comment: @user1440894 yes `nub` is quite slow

Comment: @Carsten See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67841008/11419548) for an efficient and generic (requires just `Eq`) algorithm for computing unique permutations of finite lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that `permutations` has type

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

That means that it satisfies the free theorem

```
permutations . map f = (map . map) f . permutations
```

for *all* functions `f`.  Since you can change the *elements* of the argument list arbitrarily without affecting the *structure* of the result list, `permutations` must really be a function on the indices of the original list, rather than the elements.

So what `permutations` is really doing --- what it must do --- is calculate all permutations of the *indices* of the argument list, then apply each of those permutations to the list and return the results.  (I.e.,

```
permutations xn = (map . map) (xn!!) (permutations [0..length xn - 1])
```

for finite `xn`).

Mathematical appendix:

Since

```
xn = map (xn!!) (zipWith const [0..] xn)
```

for *all* `xn`, any function with `permutations`'s type must satisfy

```
permutations xn
  = permutations (map (xn!!) (zipWith const [0..] xn)
  = (map . map) (xn!!) (permutations (zipWith const [0..] xn))
```

by the equation above for `xn` and the free theorem for `permutations`.  So any function with `permutations`'s type must operate only on the indices of the input list[1].

[1] Technically you can violate this by using `seq`.  But only for input lists that contain `undefined` as an element, which isn't true in your case.

Answer (score 7):

#### 1 - Why does Haskell implement "permutations" in the way described above (i.e. treating all elements of a list as distinct?)

It is a design question and should be studied in deep. `permutation` treats the elements of the list as if they were all different from each other. You can do `permutations [0, 0, 0]` and you'll yet get a list of lists of size **6**.

#### 2 - Are there any standard library functions that calculate the permutations of a list in the "true" sense of permutations?

Yes, you have the [`Math.Combinat.Permutations`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/combinat-0.2.7.0/docs/Math-Combinat-Permutations.html#v:permuteMultiset), but you can easily create your own definition filtering the unique combinations with a complexity of `O(n * log n)` using sets, taking account that `nub` is known by being very slow:

```
module Main where
import Data.List (permutations)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

nubOrd :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
nubOrd xs = go Set.empty xs where
  go s (x:xs)
   | x `Set.member` s = go s xs
   | otherwise        = x : go (Set.insert x s) xs
  go _ _              = []

permutations' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [[a]]
permutations' = nubOrd . permutations
```

Where `permutations' [1, 0, 0]` gives `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`.

Comment: Why reverse and re-reverse the list before and after nubbing it?

Comment: `reverse` was mean't to preserve the original order of the list, acting exactly like `unique`.

Comment: "Pure" is probably not a good word to describe what `permutations` does to the length of the list, given how strongly we associate it with the concept of a pure function. You might prefer to say "the length of the result of `permutation` depends only on the length of the argument", or simply "`permutation` treats the elements of the list as if they were all different from each other".

Comment: @duplode, I just edited it with your more concise definition. Thanks!

Comment: Filtering n! permutations is still O(n!), so you can just use `nub`  — there is almost no difference.

Comment: `nubOrd = Set.elems . Set.fromList` is simpler but not a stable filter. Given `permutations` does not produce results in lexicographic order, an un-stable filter beforehand shouldn't be a problem. the following should suffice, `permutations' = permutations . Set.elems . Set.fromList`

Answer (score 1):

> Why does Haskell implement "permutations" in the way described above (i.e. treating all elements of a list as distinct?)

Because otherwise, the type would have to be:

```
permutations :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

and then we could permute only things that have an Eq instance. But I remember I had something like

```
permutations [(+), subtract, (*), (/)]
```

in some Project Euler code ....

Comment: Project Euler is pretty good that way (I mean for making us use interesting patterns in our code).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly rearranged Daniel Fischer's [solution](https://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg49360.html):

```
inserts :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
inserts (x:xs) (y:ys) = map (x:) (inserts xs (y:ys)) ++ map (y:) (inserts (x:xs) ys)
inserts  xs     ys    = [xs ++ ys]

uniqPerms :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
uniqPerms = foldM inserts [] . group . sort
```