# Can someone explain the logic behind this permutations generation code?

Tags: haskell, permutation

Frnakly, it looks like black magic to me. Granted, my knowledge of Haskell is fairly limited, but I can understand basic principles. Just because it makes matters that much easier I try to work through a test input, but in this case it still doesn't make sense.

Background:
About a year ago I posted this question ([Are recursive calls in my "permutations with repetition" code accumulated to clog the RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67455986/are-recursive-calls-in-my-permutations-with-repetition-code-accumulated-to-clo)) about a piece of permutation generation code I was trying to get working. I received quite a lot of help from this wonderful community and went on with my project. However, there was one last answer I didn't think much of at the time, from user "peter pun" that I revisited recently.

Part of the answer, the important one, that generates permutations is this

```
permutationsNub :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
permutationsNub = foldr (concatMap . insert) [[]]
    where insert y = foldr combine [[y]] . (zip <*> tail . tails) -- tails through importing Data.List
              where combine (x, xs) xss = (y : x : xs) :
                        if y == x then [] else map (x :) xss
```

Allow me to reform the function in a way that makes more sense for me, so that I can see every argument and refer to it, because of partial application in the original and variable names that confused me. Please tell me if the interpretation is correct.

```
permutationsNub :: Eq a => [a] -> [[[a]]]
permutationsNub digits = scanr (concatMap . insert) [[]] digits
    where insert digit perms = foldr combine [[digit]] $ (zip <*> tail . tails) perms -- zip will produce  tuples of the form (a, [a])
              where combine (permX, tailOfPerms) digitAsDoubleList = (digit : permX : tailOfPerms) : 
                      if digit == permX then [] else map (permX :) digitAsDoubleList
```

I replaced the main foldr function with scanr (the output type also) to see intermediate steps, so if I run `permutationNub [2,7,7,8]` the result is `[[[2,7,7,8],[7,2,7,8],[7,7,2,8],[7,7,8,2],[2,7,8,7],[7,2,8,7],[7,8,2,7],[7,8,7,2],[2,8,7,7],[8,2,7,7],[8,7,2,7],[8,7,7,2]],[[7,7,8],[7,8,7],[8,7,7]],[[7,8],[8,7]],[[8]],[[]]]` which gives *some* insight.

So, I have to ask:

1. First of all, why is applicative notation (`<*>`) used next to `zip`? Is it dictated by the use of point free notation? How do applicatives creep into this?
2. My renaming of variables so that they make sense to me seems fine, because the function works, aka produces the same output as the original. However, some things are strange, e.g how can `digit` ever be equal to `permX` as per the comparison check in the `combine` function? The former is an Int and the latter is a [Int], otherwise cons-ing like `digit:permX:...` in the same function wouldn't work, right? For example, if we call `permutationNub [2,7,7,8]`, on the second pass of the main foldr (or scanr) function, digit will be `7` and permX will `[8]`, so how can these two ever be equal?
3. It gets stranger from here. Well, both of them can then be cons-ed to tailOfPerms, which is an [[Int]], but then this whole thing, enclosed in brackets is cons-ed to an ... [[Int]]? Again?

Actually, `map (permX :) digitAsDoubleList` doesn't seem to work (yet, somehow it does...) because we're trying to map [Int] to a [[Int]], as is the result, and then cons to that the previous [[Int]], which I don't see how it could fit.
For example, on the second pass of the `permutationNub, with 7 as the next digit, picked by the main foldr/scanr function, first pass of` insert` will be (7:[8]:[]):[[8]:[[7]]], which I can't make sense of.

4. Note: As a *higher level* explanation the author of the code says **The basic idea is that, given the unique permutations of a list's tail, we can compute the unique permutations of the whole list by inserting its head into all of the tail's permutations, in every position that doesn't follow an occurrence of the head (to avoid creating duplicates)**. So, as an example, let's say that current permutations of the tail
   are [[7,8],[8,7]] (see pass 2) and the next digit is 7. So, the algorithm will insert 7 at the beginning of the first permutation (producing [7,7,8], then at the end (producing [7,8,7] and then only at the beginning of the second permutation (producing [8,7,7])? How can it tell that it doesn't need to elsewhere? What does the author mean by **in every position that doesn't follow an occurrence of the head**?

If anyone can shed some light into this piece of coding wizardry, please do so!

Comment: `zip <*> tail` is a classic code-golf way to write `\xs -> zip xs (tail xs)`. It uses the Applicative instance for functions. `zip <*> tail . tails` is the same thing, just using `tail (tails xs)` instead.

Comment: @amalloy *It uses the Applicative instance for functions* is exactly what I needed to search for, and it makes sense now. I guess I can write this one off my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is just a modification of the classic insertion-based one, which you can find for example in [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Haskell). To my surprise, despite its simplicity, I wasn't able to find it mentioned anywhere.

First of all, for the insertions, instead of using explicit recursion (considered harmful), I simulated, somewhat clumsily, a [paramorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317242/what-are-paramorphisms) for lists. Then I found that, if we stop producing insertions after finding an occurrence of the value to be inserted, we can prevent the creation of duplicates while at the same time producing every permutation. I hope the following code clarifies things:

```hs
parafoldr :: ((a, [a]) -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
parafoldr f y xs = foldr f y $ zip xs $ tail $ tails xs

insertions :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
insertions y = parafoldr combine [[y]]
    where combine (x, xs) xss = (y : x : xs) : map (x :) xss
--or equivalently
insertions y xs = (y : xs) : (parafoldr combine [] xs)
    where combine (x, xs) xss = (x : y : xs) : map (x :) xss

permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations = foldr (concatMap . insertions) [[]]

insertions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
insertions' y = parafoldr combine [[y]]
    where combine (x, xs) xss = (y : x : xs) :
              if x == y then [] else map (x :) xss
--or equivalently
insertions' y xs = (y : xs) : (parafoldr combine [] xs)
    where combine (x, xs) xss
              | x == y    = []
              | otherwise = (x : y : xs) : map (x :) xss

permutationsNub :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
permutationsNub = foldr (concatMap . insertions') [[]]
```

It's not too hard to show by induction that:

- given the correctness of `permutations`, `permutationsNub` produces every permutation that `permutations` produces and, of course, no other lists
- the permutations produced by `permutationsNub` are pairwise different

---

But actually, I arrived at this algorithm indirectly. Permutations fit naturally in a relational setting (look at the answer's end for references). In the following I use an informal pseudo-Haskell notation to write about relations. I denote by `a ~> b` the type of relations from `a` to `b`. I write `r(x, y)` when `r` relates `x` to `y`. When defining a relation, I suppose that the relation defined is the least one satisfying the given conditions. I denote by `relfoldr` (`relunfoldr`) the operation of relational catamorphism (anamorphism) for lists and by `converse` (guess what) the converse operation.

So consider the following relations:

- `permutation :: [a] ~> [a]`;  `permutation(x, y)` if `y` is a permutation of `x`
- `insertion :: Maybe (a, [a]) ~> [a]`; `insertion(Nothing, [])` and `insertion(Just (x, xs), xs')` if `xs'` results from inserting `x` somewhere in `xs`
- `insertion'` same as `insertion` but with "`xs'` results from inserting `x` somewhere in `xs` ***but not after an occurrence of it*** "
- `selection :: [a] ~> Maybe (a, [a])`; `selection([], Nothing)` and `selection(xs, Just (x, xs'))` if `xs'` results from deleting an occurrence of `x` in `xs`
- `selection'` same as `selection` but with "`xs'` results from deleting ***the first*** occurrence of `x` in `xs`"

Notice that `permutation == converse permutation`, `insertion == converse selection` and `insertion' == converse selection'`. Knowing that `relfoldr (converse r) == converse (relunfoldr r)`, I proceeded roughly as follows:

```
permutation ==
relfoldr insertion ==
converse (relunfoldr selection) ==
converse (relunfoldr selection') ==
relfoldr insertion'
```

The first equality is known. Because of the symmetry of `permutation` we have `permutation == relunfoldr selection`, which helps us justify that `relunfoldr selection == relunfoldr selection'` and thus the third equality.

Now, with a bit of imagination, we can see that:

- `relunfoldr selection` gives the classic selection-based algorithm
- `relunfoldr selection'` gives a similar selection-based algorithm that doesn't create duplicates
- `relfoldr insertion` gives the classic insertion-based algorithm (named `permutations` above)
- `relfoldr insertion'` gives a similar insertion-based algorithm that doesn't create duplicates (named `permutationsNub` above)

Some advantages of the insertion-based no-duplicate algorithm over the selection-based one are that:

- the latter needs some kind of memory to check if a selection has already been made, which makes it less efficient and possibly less general (depending on the memory's type, it may require `Ord a`, `Hashable a` or `Int` instead of just `Eq a`)
- the former has a simple implementation using `foldr`

Before answering the old question, I made an attempt to simulate several things from **REL** in **CPO** and implement them in Haskell but I found out that there were some limitations and a lot of details that I needed to work out. I was also interested in properly handling infinity via laziness but some tricks I tried, like diagonalization/dovetailing and using `NonEmpty` lists, didn't work and I wasn't sure about the appropriate theoretical framework either. I might revisit this area some time, if I find the time/energy/motivation.

---

Finally, here are a few references:

- The classic [bananas paper](https://maartenfokkinga.github.io/utwente/mmf91m.pdf) treats recursion schemes (and more) in **CPO**.
- The book [Algebra of Programming](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/publications/publication2634-abstract.html) focuses on the relational setting. In pages 130-131 it touches on permutations and derives the classic insertion-based algorithm.
- The book [Algorithm Design with Haskell](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/publications/books/adwh/) is more practically-oriented but still gives an emphasis on equational reasoning. Permutations have a distinct presence in it and both selection/insertion-based basic algorithms are presented.
- In the lecture notes "Algebraic and Coalgebraic Methods in the Mathematics of Program Construction" you can find some quite pedagogical expositions of related matters. [Chapter 5](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/acmmpc-calcfp.pdf) takes the functional approach (**SET**, **CPO**) while [chapter 8](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/acmmpc-optimization.pdf) adopts the relational one.

Answer (score 0):

Αfter a couple of days, some things make more sense and I realise I've made two mistakes.

The first is about cons-ing values. I have mistakenly, for whatever reason, thought that consecutive values have to be of successive levels of nesting, like a:[b]:[[c]] while that only applies to the last value in the chain of cons operators, like a:b:c:[d].

The second is that I misunderstood, due to unfamiliarity with concatMap, how the insert function is called. Let's assume for example that (if as mentioned in my question we run `permutationNub [2,7,7,8]")` we' re at the end of the
second pass of the main foldr/scanr, where acc is now populated with [[7,8],[8,7]] (as the use of scanr has kindly informed us). The use of concatMap means that insert will be applied to every argument in that acc list, one by one, not at the same time, and the result of that mapping function will be concatenated. So for that particular acc content, insert will be executed twice, the first time as `insert 7 [7,8]` and the second as `insert 7 [8,7]`. **Not** in any case once `insert 7 [[7,8],[8,7]]`.

Which leads me to once again to reform the whole function as such

```
permutationsNub :: Eq a => [a] -> [[[a]]]
permutationsNub digits = scanr (concatMap . insert) [[]] digits 
    where insert digit permutationN = foldr combine [[digit]] $ (zip <*> tail . tails) permutationN 
              where combine (x, xs) accOfInsert = (digit : x : xs) : -- (x, xs) of permutationN e.g [7,[8]]
                      if digit == x then [] else map (x:) accOfInsert
```

After that, things fall into place more nicely. For `insert 7 [7,8]` the zipping part will produce `[(7,[8]),(8,[])]`. Afterwards, insert's own foldr function will pick those tuples one by one and call `combine` on each of them.

For example, in the course of the same execution, combine will also be called twice, once as `combine (8,[]) [[7]]` and once as `combine (7,[8]) [[7,8,7],[8,7]]` ([[7,8,7],[8,7]] being the result of the first combine call, hence now acc value in the foldr loop), which will result in [[7,7,8]] . It is now crystal clear that `digit` and `x` are now comparable as `Ints`, and if they are the same, the tail of elements in the current permutation will be ignored (replaced by [], consed at the end, as it happens in the second pass of combine.

Similarly, for `insert 7 [8,7]` zipping will produce tuples [(8,[7]),(7,[])], and combine will be called as `combine (7,[]) [[7]]` and `combine (8,[7]) [[7,7]]`, which will result in [[7,8,7],[8,7,7]].

Lastly the results of the mapping function, [[[7,7,8]],[[7,8,7],[8,7,7]]] will be concatenated into [[7,7,8],[7,8,7],[8,7,7]]. And the last loop with digit=2 will begin. Phew!

I can sort of see now what peter_pun means by "inserting the digit in every possible position of the permutation" etc, though I still consider the algorithm a brilliant approach, certainly something I couldn't have come up with myself. I became determined to understand it before using it, because I though it was somehow important, no less because it is at least an order of magnitude faster than my own permutation generation code. Still haven't fully grasped it, though. Maybe I'm missing some necessary theoritical background atm. Oh well...

I hope this helps someone in a similar situation. It also goes without saying that any additional feedback/comment is highly appreciated.

Cheers!